# Found an issue while migrating from Subverison to git invalid XML at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 308

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

I am migrating `svn` respository which have `63000revisions` into `git`.

In the process of migration I found below the issue and using `SVN2GIT` plugin for migration in windows machine.

> XML data was not well-formed: The XML response contains invalid XML at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 308.

Please suggest a solution to fix this issue.